# MySQL INSERT query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a simple MySQL INSERT query but it seems to not work... I entered it directly in PHPmyAdmin and it works, but not in PHP...

There's my code:

```
<?php
$id = rand(0000,9999);
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_id']);
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
$blog_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['blog_id']);
$moderated = 1;
$date = date("Y\-m\-d");
$time = date("H\:i\:s");

if ($user_id != "" && $content != "" && $blog_id != "")
{
    include('php/connect_db.php');
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `comments`  (`id`,`user_id`,`content`,`blog_id`,`moderated`,`date`,`time`) VALUES ('".$id."','".$user_id."','".$content."','".$blog_id."','".$moderated."','".$date."','".$time."')");
    header('Location: blog.php?id='.$blog_id.'#comments');
}
else
{
    header('Location: blog.php?id='.$blog_id.'&error#comments');
}
?>
```

It doesn't work but I don't know why...

`connect_db.php`

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect to database: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);
?>
```

Comment: What error message do you get? Please always post the related error.

Comment: I don't get any error message...!

Comment: Are all your data types actually strings, or is user_id numeric?

Comment: Instead of doing the redirect, try printing out `mysql_error()`

Comment: What is your `connect_db.php` (without passwords and hosts).

Comment: is 2012. why is not everybody using PDO or mysqli?

Comment: basic debugging, echo the actual query run, check for mysql errors

Comment: [mysql_error](http://www.php.net/mysql_error) is your friend, use it.

Comment: Are you certain it didn't throw an error message before you redirected away with `header()`? comment out the `header()` call and `echo mysql_error()`

Comment: @ElzoValugi: plenty of legacy applications. I agree it shouldn't be used for new projects though.

Comment: echo query... see how its build and run it in mysql see what happen.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I added the code of `connect_db.php`.
@MikeChristensen Yeah.
@klaustopher I tried. But it doesn't work...

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux, seen that, see the answer.

Comment: @ElzoValugi: too many tutorials and examples out there using old PHP4 methods...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not including the `config.cms.php` that contains the connexion info to database. FAIL!

Now it works great!

Comment: Haha, yeah, that is always a good thing ;) Well, as Wrikken posted - it is always a good idea to use mysql_error, and as Michael posted - please remember to include error messages in your posts :) That will make the job easier for us when helping ;)

Answer (score -2):

I notice that you're using the character ` instead of the character '.

Is this throwing PHP off?

Comment: it's not "instead of", it's mysql identifier quoting.

Comment: The usage of ` is right here ... It is used to escape the table and column names

Comment: You learn something new every day. How humiliating! Thanks for the info.